# Why can I not login on my Laravel App even if using "Attempt" in my cases?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

After using attempt in this following first method to connect to my custom auth:

```
public function login(Request $request) {        
    $this->validate($request, ['loginuserprest' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);        
    $user = $request->all();       
    Auth::attempt($user);        
    return redirect('/');    
}
```

I get the "**this password does not use the bcrypt algorithm**" error.

And when I change by doing this following `login` method:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    // dd($request->all());        $credentials = $request->only('loginuserprest', 'password');        
    // if (Auth::attempt ( array('loginuserprest' => $request->get('loginuserprest'), 'password' => $request->get('password'))))        
    //dd($credentials);
        // $user = Userprest::where('loginuserprest', $request->loginuserprest)->first();
        $user = Userprest::where('loginuserprest', $request->loginuserprest)->first();        
    //dd(Hash::check($request->password, $user->password));
        if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) ) {            
        // dd('Authentication successful');             
        Auth::login($user);
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user instanceof Userprest && !$user->estsuspendu) {                
            $token = $user->createToken($user->loginuserprest)->plainTextToken;
                $userResponse = [                    
                "id" => $user->id,                    
                "coduserprest" => $user->coduserprest,                    
                "loginuserprest" => $user->loginuserprest,                    
                "nomuserprest" => $user->nomuserprest,                    
                "prenomprest" => $user->prenomprest,                    
                "codprestataire" => $user->codprestataire,                    
                "estsuspendu" => $user->estsuspendu,                    
                "email" => $user->email
                ];
                return response()->json([                    
                "success" => true,                    
                "user" => $userResponse,                    
                "token" => $token,                    
                "message" => "Connecté avec succès"                
            ], 200);            
        } else {                
            return response()->json([                    
                "success" => false,                    
                "message" => "Your account has been suspended, please contact the Admin"                
            ], 401);            
        }        
    } else {            
        // dd('Authentication failed');            
        return response()->json([                
            "success" => false,                
            "message" => "Le login ou mot de passe incorrect."            
        ], 403);        
    }    
}
```

I get false error like `Le login ou mot de passe incorrect.` even if loginuserprest and Password are correct after I just created account using `bcrypt()` method or `Hash::make()` to Hash password when registering account.

Please, I need your help because I no longer know what to do to correct my Laravel custom Login Method ???

Thanks for your help.